# Can I write somethings like a Notification in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c

In Objective-C I use a Notification to do some tasks, which required some time to process. I can listen to the Notification, until it is ready...
For example:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:objectB
                                           selector:@selector(objectReceived:)
                                               name:@"objectATasks"
                                             object:nil];
  [objectA doALongProcess];
```

When the objectA is finished the task, the @"objectATasks" will be fired, and the objectB's objectReceived: will be called. Do have have similar things / concept in java? Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [Observer](http://www.vogella.de/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) design pattern in java

Comment: [Here](http://ayp-sd.blogspot.com/2013/01/observer-design-pattern-in-java.html) you can find another implementation of Observer design pattern in Java. It might look a bit complicated at first glance, but it uses generics and some other modern Java facilities.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are using the observer pattern, of course you can implement it also in Java, take a look [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) .

Answer (score 1):

The closest to that in "stock" Java is a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), but that doesn't let you add continuations. You may want to use the [`ListenableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) interface in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) with its `addListener` method. Then you can use [`MoreExecutors`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html) to create a [`ListeningExecutorService`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html) - you submit tasks to that, which gives back a `ListenableFuture`.

(The point of using this instead of rolling your own implementation of the `Observer` pattern is that it's already done for you in a way which is specifically designed for this sort of use case, reacting to a task being completed - rather than the various other kinds of observer implementations which may be reacting to just properties changing etc, without considering thread safety. Why design your own API when smart people have already done it for you?)

Comment: I'm probably observing a glitch in the universe. I found a Jon Skeet answer that took two minutes to write, is the most comprehensive, yet isn't the accepted choice.